# Java Linear Search of Array with Multiple Key Matches

Tags: java, arrays, jgrasp

Trying to implement a program that does the following:

-Program that can be re-run by user input (while loop)

-Allows user to input a desired array size, creates an array of that size,
uses a for loop to enter elements into the array, and enter a desired key 
from which to do a linear search method

I want to modify the **linear search** method to return, as an array, **the index values of all the instances where the arrayName[i] == key value**; this is the part where I'm getting stuck.

For example, if as the user I input 4 as array size; 1, 2, 2, 3 as the elements; 2 as the desired key for the linear search, then it would print the array {1, 2} as the indices where the key matched the element value.

Here's my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner; //Imports Scanner from java.util package

public class LinearSearch2 {
  public static void main (String[] args) {

    //Creates Scanner object for user to input string whether to run program
    Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Run linear search on an array? ");
    System.out.print("(Y = Yes; Type any other character to exit program): ");
    String s = input1.next();
    char runProgram = s.charAt(0);

    /*While loop (this allows for re-running the program with a different 
    set of inputs in the same run depending on the string Scanner object 
    input...see while loop-continuation condition below)*/ 
    while (runProgram == 'y' || runProgram == 'Y') {
      //Creates another Scanner object for entering the array size as integer
      Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);

      //Scans in user input of array size
      System.out.print("Enter desired array size: ");
      int arraySize = input2.nextInt();

      //Creates array based on size input
      double [] numberArray = new double[arraySize];

      //Creates another Scanner object for entering the array numbers as doubles
      Scanner input3 = new Scanner(System.in);

      //Loop to read in input numbers into created array
      for (int i = 0; i < numberArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        numberArray[i] = input3.nextDouble();
      }

      //Creates another Scanner object for entering the key as a doubles
      Scanner input4 = new Scanner(System.in);

      //Scans in user desired key 
      System.out.print("Enter desired key: ");
      double arrayKey = input4.nextDouble();

      //Invokes linear search method
      int [] keyIndices = linearSearch(numberArray,arrayKey);

      //Prints keyIndices array
      for (int i = 0; i < keyIndices.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(keyIndices[i] + " ");
      }

      //Requests if user would like to re-run the program
      System.out.println("Do another linear search on an array? ");
      System.out.print("(Y = Yes; Type any other character to exit program): ");
      //Takes new result of string scanner object to determine if to run the program again or exit
      String s2 = input1.next();
      runProgram = s2.charAt(0);
    }
  }

  //Revised linear search method
  public static int [] linearSearch(double[] list, double key) {
    int [] resultKeyIndices = new int[];
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      if (key == list[i]){
        return i;
      }
    }
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify exactly where you are getting stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is to allocate an array of the right size (number of matches). This solution uses a large array and resize it at the end:

```
  public static int [] linearSearch(double[] list, double key) {
    int[] indices = int[list.length];
    int n = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      if (key == list[i]){
        îndices[n++] = i;
      }
    }
    int[] result = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        result[i] = indices[i];
    }
    return result;
  }
```